# What is wrong with this FTP server?

Tags: ftp, hosting, sftp, timeout

Trying to upload files to a web host and the FTP server seems awful.

I keep getting the error

`Error: The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out`

And when I retry I get `Status: ftpcontrolsocket.cpp(1871): Waiting for replies to skip before sending next command`

Comment: If you are using filezilla as a client, please attempt to research the error before asking here. If you are not, please detail the server and  client software involved and post any relevant logs.

Comment: Passive or active? Any firewall/NAT in it? FTP is well known to possibly be - ah - "problematic" with NAT devices, although by now all should handle it well.

Comment: I am using FileZilla and have googled the errors but not found a solution. I have configured the client for active mode - entering my external IP as well as a port range, which I have forwarded on my router. However when I connect it changes to Passive mode, and if I try to force Active I get `Error: Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing`